# How to run Celery Periodic task at every end of the month

Tags: python, django, django-celery, periodic-task

Basically, I have a task to generate Invoice. So I have created a function `generate_invoice()` in my **tasks.py** file.

Now, I am using `@periodic_task` to call the function. But I need my task to run only on the last date of the month **around 11:55 pm - 11:57 pm**.

I am getting the last date of month using this function:

```
def get_last_date():
        today = timezone.now()
        year = today.year
        month = today.month
        last_date = calendar.monthrange(year, month)[1]
        return str(last_date)
```

My code for **task** looks like this:

```
@periodic_task(run_every=(crontab(day_of_month=get_last_date())), name="invoice_simulation", ignore_result=True)
def invoice_simulation():
    generate_invoice()
```

But this is not working!

Or is there any better way to implement this feature then please suggest.

Comment: How i did this task: Get the first day of the next month (12:01am), convert to dt obj and subtract 5 minutes. I don't think there is an easy "run every" as that is relative to the month. If you "run at"  this can work.  My exp is not in celery as I have generally written my own wrappers and cron tasks from scratch, so this solution may not convert cleanly.  We had the exact same problem in a start-up and this approach worked great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A rather simpler solution would be to run the schedule every day at 11:55 PM, and check inside the task if today is the last day of the month. If so, generate the invoice. If not then simply do nothing.

Something like:

```
@periodic_task(run_every=(crontab(hour=23, minute=55)), name="invoice_simulation", ignore_result=True)
def invoice_simulation():
    if timezone.now().day == get_last_date():
        generate_invoice()
```

Just make sure that `timezone` and `crontab` do not conflict each other. Both must either be TZ aware (or in UTC), or use naive times for both.

Comment: for testing, I have given ```crontab(hour=1, minute=22)``` so, that it runs now and I can see but it is not executed at this time.

Comment: @ShubhamSrivastava You're welcome. Could you mark it as an answer if it solves your question? Thanks ^_^

Answer (score -1):

Update your get_last_date() function as follows.

```
def get_last_date():
    today = datetime.date.today()
    year = today.year
    month = today.month
    last_date = calendar.monthrange(year, month)
    return str(last_date)
```

Comment: throwing error: ```ValueError: Invalid weekday literal '(4'``` when this value returns to ```@periodic_tasks```